# I would like to get Words plotted instead of numbers

Tags: r

I am learning how to plot a word cloud using term frequency and TF-IDF.
I have converted the document term matrix into a standard matrix and then using word cloud trying to plot it but it is plotting numbers instead of words.

```
tweet.matrix = as.matrix(tweet.dtm) # converting to a standard R matrix


freqs = rowSums(tweet.matrix)

wordcloud(names(freqs), max.words =30, freqs, random.order=FALSE, min.freq=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error.
So in the bellow part of the code it should be colSums instead of rowSums

```
freqs = rowSums(tweet.matrix)
```

The correct code is :

```
freqs = colSums(tweet.matrix)
```